# Deactivate Apache Rewrite for Folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an Apache web server with default settings, I didn't add any rewrite rules to it.

When I request a file through my application, if the file doesn't exist then Apache returns another file with a close name to the original name. The GET return is 301. I don't want this behavior but I am not sure how to disable it.

I attempted several solutions I found online, but none seem to work. Here are my attempts:

- I added a .htaccess file with a `RewriteEngine Off`
- I added a .htaccess file with a `RewriteEngine On` but without any other lines or rules for the rewrite. One person online suggested that this is similar to turning it off.
- I added a `<Directory>` directive in httpd.conf, with only one line in it: `RewriteEngine Off`. I attempted the Directory two times, one time with a full path, and another time with a path starting after the domain name. For example, the link is `www.domain.com/some/path/file.flv`. My first attempt was `<Directory "/root/to/some/path/">` and the second attempt was `<Directory "/some/path/">`.

None of these attempts have worked and I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

**UPDATE 1:**

My application is a Flex Application created with the Flex SDK. I have Adobe Media Server installed on my server. My application loads a video file by setting the source property of the VideoDisplay object to (for example):
`"/some/path/123_video.flv"`.

Now if that file doesn't exist, and I have a file called: `"124_video.flv"` then this other file will be played instead and my `/var/log/httpd/access_log` will have a line with `GET 301` return value.

I am sure that I send the correct file name from my application. The `access_log` even shows my file's name (`123_video.flv` in this example) but with a `301` return code and then my application plays the other video (`124_video.flv`).

As a test, I disabled the `mod_rewrite.so` module in my `httpd.conf` (by commenting the line with `#`) and I started getting `500` as a return code for files that didn't exist.

What is more strange, I just did a quick test again, I went through my httpd.conf and changed all `AllowOverride All` to `AllowOverride None` restarted the httpd server and I still got the `301` code!!

I even commented the `mod_rewrite.so` again and restarted the server.. and I got the same result `301`!!

I think my last test has something else wrong in it, but not sure what.

Comment: *`When I request a file through my application, if the file doesn't exist then Apache returns another file with a close name to the original name.`* — That's not the default behavior for sure. Can you provide a few examples please?

Comment: And what do you exactly mean by *`request a file through my application`*? Maybe it's your application, not the web server.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Please check UPDATE 1.

Comment: So you're sure that it's Apache, not your app. Now to narrow down the issue you must be sure if it's happening in the htaccess files or apache main config files (like the main httpd.conf and vhosts file). I don't know about your app, but browsers tend to cache `301` redirects aggressively. Might be the reason for the second `301` after commenting the `mod_rewrite.so` line. To narrow this further, let's remove the app from the question, use a 3rd-party http client to see what happens if you request that non-existing flv file. Use Redirect Detective for example. And can I see your httpd.conf?

Comment: [Redirect Detective](http://redirectdetective.com/). And what the `ErrorDocument` directive for `404` is set to?

Comment: I have only one htaccess file in a parent directory for the folder in which the videos are being accessed.

Comment: I have only one htaccess file in a parent directory (not the direct parent though) for the folder in which the videos are being accessed. The htaccess has the following lines:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^go\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /public/urlresolver.php?search=$1
</IfModule>

Comment: Does the 301 cache survive clearing the browser's cache clearing? I always clear the cache before any test.
Unfortunately I couldn't use the Redirect Detective tool because I am performing these attempts on a test server residing on a virtual host. Redirect Detective couldn't reach my server, I got a 404. I tried to expose my server in my router using DMZ but it's not working for some reason.

Comment: I did some tests on  the production server and it doesn't seem to have the same 301 problem. Which means the problem doesn't exist on the production server and answering this question is not urgent anymore. However, I would like to continue trying to figure out the reason for this behavior on the test server.

Comment: Click here to view my 
[httpd.conf](https://gist.github.com/MBarjawi/7fb8144b66140ae25931d04a3296bddf) file.